# Testing Braintree Transparent Redirect for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, braintree

I'm using Braintree Transparent Redirect to take payment info and create subscriptions that are stored with Braintree.  What are best practices for testing the controller that interacts with Braintree?  It seems like a lot of trouble to create a new customer and subscription in the Braintree sandbox every time I run my test.  I'm using Rspec if that matters at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're still interested in using Rspec, check out the braintree ruby examples on github. All the tests are rspec, and there are lots of examples you can use.

https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby_examples

Comment: Nice!  This definitely helps.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hey try this out, in the process of setting up BT myself right now, planning to do testing this way roughly: http://www.enlightsolutions.com/articles/integration-testing-braintrees-transparent-redirect-with-rails-and-cucumber/

Comment: Thanks.  I had come across the post in my searching, but I was hoping there would be a way to do it with rspec.  Looks like this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fake_braintree](https://github.com/thoughtbot/fake_braintree) to speed up your tests.

> "This library is a way to test Braintree code without hitting Braintree's servers. It uses Capybara::Server to intercept all of the calls from Braintree's Ruby library and returns XML that the Braintree library can parse. The whole point is not to hit the Braintree API."

Or, if it doesn't do all you need, you can use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) with either the default java script driver or the [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) gem to test the transparent redirects.